# Correct way to say "by itself"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, pronouns

I was just talking to someone and the conversation went like this:

> "I didn't get those shoes because they were pretty bulky. The pair I got is pretty bulky **itself**"

Now, I feel like "itself" isn't the correct word to use there, and I called them out for it, but I just can't think about the right way to say it. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: You called them out about it even though you didn't have a better alternative? That's...bold of you. You haven't said why you think "itself" was incorrect in that context.

Comment: You could say, “But the ones I got were also pretty bulky.”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would say:

> I didn’t get those shoes because they were pretty bulky. The pair I got are pretty bulky themselves.

You clearly got these shoes not those shoes.

Similarly, you might say:

> I’ve misplaced a pair of my favorite shoes. I wonder where they are.

or

> No thanks, I already have a pair of shoes.

> Great, I can’t wait to see them!

You wouldn’t say that you couldn’t wait to see “it”, because most people would not call a pair of shoes an *it* in these circumstances. Here they’re a *they*. It’s how *couple* can be construed as either singular or plural, depending on the circumstances and the speaker’s intent.

Comment: @nnnnnn Tpyo, sorry.

Comment: I figured. Anyway, I agree with your examples, but on the other hand I'm fine with a sentence like "That is a nice pair of shoes", and don't like "they are a nice pair of shoes". Sometimes it seems treating the pair as a unit - an *it* - makes sense, sometimes treating the shoes that make up the pair as a *they* makes sense.

Comment: This is can-of-worms time. Divided usage. And that's just me! "I'm looking for some new binoculars – how much is that pair, please?" But as you say "This pair of shoes are on their last legs." Certainly "This is my favourite pair of shoes."